# Why does my Ps3 lag/skip/freeze

Tags: ps3

Ive had my Ps3 for 7 years its the Fat 80 GB version i know its old but ive cleaned it and im thinking of replacing the thermal paste. The main games it Freezes or skeps is Cod ghosts and advanced warfare. PLEASE HELP

Comment: Like was said in your previous question, if you've disassembled your PS3 to the point of being able to see the thermal paste, you seriously need to replace it.  Not doing so runs the risk of doing permanent damage, which no amount of thermal paste will solve.

Comment: It's also likely the cause of your issues here, and by not replacing it, you've probably already caused permanent damage.  Sorry, realized I hadn't mentioned that part.  No thermal paste = bad things happening when trying to use the system.

Comment: after use what should it look like. mines snowflaky patern and is crusty

Comment: I'm not sure how often I can tell you; if you can see your thermal paste, **you need to replace it**. If you want your PS3 to work, its not really an optional step.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your PlayStation 3 is reaching the end of its life. I am fairly surprised you've lasted this long without the YOLD (Yellow Light of Death). My Fat PlayStation 3 lasted no where near 7 years before I had to start applying thermal compound to it. That being said, applying thermal compound to a PlayStation 3 isn't a long term fix. I had to use a heatgun on the CPU/GPU and reapply thermal compound at least once every two weeks and sometime within the same week and it eventually got to the point that even with the fix the fan would run at really high speeds and was very loud.

Also applying a new layer of thermal compound may not even work in this case as it is likely, given the age of the console that the CPU/GPU are too far gone by this point that the fix would simply do nothing.

7 years is a good run but it looks like your PlayStation 3 is on its last legs.

Comment: ok well its still going strong its never getting hot the highest the fans ever gottne to is level 3. but this is the only problem iv ever had with it

Comment: Temperature may not even be the issue here. Freezing and skipping is a sign that the processing chips on your console are unable to cope with the demand the games place on them. The freezing is caused by the CPU/GPU not being able to process the data fast enough so it essentially gives itself time to process that data by freezing the game. Old age can cause these issues just as easily as temperature can.